# Should I discourage this behavior?

Tags: discussion

[This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/200890/which-ms-dos-game-is-this-screenshot-from) has several comments saying something like "I googled your picture and found it right away, do a search."

Should we discourage this behavior?

Comment: Teach a man to fish...

Comment: Not everyone knows how to use Google to search using an image.  Just like not everyone knows the appropriate keywords to find answers to other issues.  The appropriate action is to give the answer and explain how you reached that answer.

Answer (score 26):

I don't see anything wrong with letting the user know about the Google Image search feature, so long as they're not a jerk about it (remember, [be nice](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/lets-be-nice-to-each-other)). A lot of people don't actually know it exists, so it's a helpful thing to comment with.

Comment: Yup - as long as it is polite, helping them learn how to solve similar problems in the future is a great use of the comment system.